# Display Tabbed Documents Vertically instead of Horizontally

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've attempted to navigate the Options menu in Visual Studio to no avail. How can I change Visual Studio 2010 to display tabbed documents vertically instead of the default horizontally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>Right-click on the tab of the file that you are viewing and select **New Vertical Tab Group**.</del>

And once you have a vertical tab group opened, you can just click and drag files to that vertical pane.

### Edit

It looks like this functionality is [available through *Pro Power Tools* for Visual Studio](http://blog.tabsstudio.com/2010/06/08/visual-studio-2010-pro-power-tools-add-new-document-tab-well-options/).

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. Instead of displaying all open files as horizontal tabs. I would like them to run as vertical tabs down the left side of the IDE

Comment: @aahrens Oh, I see what you're saying.  I'm not sure you can do that.  Have you seen this done before??

Comment: I've seen this done on other developer machines. Not sure if it was a PowerTools plugin or if it's native to Visual Studio

Comment: @aahrens http://blog.tabsstudio.com/2010/06/08/visual-studio-2010-pro-power-tools-add-new-document-tab-well-options/ it looks like it is in Pro Power Tools.

Comment: +1 Power Tools is awesome! Why didn't they include this functionality in the IDE by default?

Answer (score 0):

There is an update regarding to this question.

Visual Studio tabs maybe positioned vertically on the left or right rather than on top of your code files. This is possible from Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4+.

Also grouping with in different colors is also possible.

Just go to Tools > Options window. Under "Environment" section you can find Tabs and windows. You can set your desired settings.

[image: Options window]

It will look something like this:

[image: visual studio result]